# "No module named Django" Problem on MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, django

I'm using `Python3.7.1` and `Django 2.0` has been installed successfully through `pip3` command on Terminal on MacOS Mojave. Pip list indicates that there is actually an installed Django on my computer.

However, when I run the code `import django`, an error is raised: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django`. I've tried reinstall django through pip but everything stays the same. Other packages like `matplotlib`, `xlrd` and etc. installed by pip3 are all imported successfully.

This is really confusing me.

Comment: How are you running the script that tries to import django?

Comment: I am using command `python3` on Terminal to start Python shell, and then import django.

Comment: Can you try running `python3 -m pip freeze` and checking if django is there. This ensures that the pip you are running is for the same interpreter you are running

Comment: For python3 I try to always run pip as "python3 -m pip" as it ensures I am updating the correct interpreter

Comment: Run `python3 -m pip install django`

Comment: Actually there is no `django` found when `freeze` command is running. I tried `python3 -m pip` command and django was successfully imported! This advice really helps a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help